# Get display name of javax.money.CurrencyUnit

Tags: java, joda-money, java-money, jsr354

I have an instance of `javax.money.CurrencyUnit` and I want to display what is it's name in a given locale (for example "US Dollars", "Euro", "Japenese Yen", etc). I've read all the documentation but the only thing I was able to find is how to format a `MonetaryAmount`:

```
MonetaryFormats.getAmountFormat(AmountFormatQueryBuilder.of(Locale.US).set(CurrencyStyle.NAME).set("pattern", "00,00,00,00.00 ¤").build()).format(myCurrencyUnit);
```

And I can see there I specify `CurrencyStyle.NAME` so it will return the currency name in the result, but the problem is I don't have a `MonetaryAmount` and I couldn't find a formatter for `CurrencyUnit`.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

What I see from code is that JavaMoney doesn't support such concept as Currency Display Name. The `CurrencyStyle.NAME` tries to resolve Display Name from JDK Currency.

```
/**
 * This method tries to evaluate the localized display name for a
 * {@link CurrencyUnit}. It uses {@link Currency#getDisplayName(Locale)} if
 * the given currency code maps to a JDK {@link Currency} instance.
 * <p>
 * If not found {@code currency.getCurrencyCode()} is returned.
 *
 * @param currency The currency, not {@code null}
 * @return the formatted currency name.
 */
private String getCurrencyName(CurrencyUnit currency) {
    Currency jdkCurrency = getCurrency(currency.getCurrencyCode());
    if (Objects.nonNull(jdkCurrency)) {
        return jdkCurrency.getDisplayName(locale);
    }
    return currency.getCurrencyCode();
}
```

Thus you can't get display name for custom currencies like BitCoins.
It was created a feature request [Get display name/symbol of a CurrencyUnit](https://github.com/JavaMoney/jsr354-api/issues/58)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for raising this. Indeed version 1 of JavaMoney/Money JSR relies on the built in JDK resources. We discuss a new version due to demands like this one and others, please feel free to follow or comment on https://github.com/JavaMoney/jsr354-api/issues/58 in the Java Money API issue tracker.